# How to use the same clock view to display different times zones? Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am realizing a list with different clocks that should give me different times. Unfortunately I lack a bit of knowledge how to implement this.

My situation:
The clock in my list is generated via TestView(). In the TestView I display a clock with the current time. Now I want to display different clocks and times in my list. For this I created a file "Country", which gives me a city name and a time zone.
How would I have to pass the values of the specific time zone to the TestView so that the time is displayed in the clock?

Here is my Code how i create a clock with de current file:

```
 struct Hand: Shape {
    let inset: CGFloat
    let angle: Angle
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let rect = rect.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
        var p = Path()
        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        p.addLine(to: position(for: CGFloat(angle.radians), in: rect))
        return p
    }
    
    private func position(for angle: CGFloat, in rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        let angle = angle - (.pi/2)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height)/2
        let xPos = rect.midX + (radius * cos(angle))
        let yPos = rect.midY + (radius * sin(angle))
        return CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
    }
}

struct TickHands: View {
    var scale: Double
    @State private var dateTime = Date()
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Hand(inset: 65 * scale, angle: dateTime.hourAngle)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Hand(inset: 40 * scale, angle: dateTime.minuteAngle)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.5 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Hand(inset: 20 * scale, angle: dateTime.secondAngle)
                .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.5 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Circle().fill(Color.orange).frame(width: 10 * scale)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { (input) in
            self.dateTime = input
        }
    }
}

extension Date {
    var hourAngle: Angle {
        return Angle (degrees: (360 / 12) * (self.hour + self.minutes / 60))
    }
    var minuteAngle: Angle {
        return Angle(degrees: (self.minutes * 360 / 60))
    }
    var secondAngle: Angle {
        return Angle (degrees: (self.seconds * 360 / 60))
    }
}

extension Date {
    var hour: Double {
        return Double(Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self))
    }
    var minutes: Double {
        return Double(Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self))
    }
    var seconds: Double {
        return Double(Calendar.current.component(.second, from: self))
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    var clockSize: CGFloat = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                let scale = geometry.size.height / 200
                TickHands(scale: scale)
                ForEach(0..<60*4) { tick in
                    Ticks.tick(at: tick, scale: scale)
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: clockSize, height: clockSize)
    }
}

struct Ticks{
    static func tick(at tick: Int, scale: CGFloat) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.primary)
                .opacity(tick % 20 == 0 ? 1 : 0.4)
                .frame(width: 2 * scale, height: (tick % 5 == 0 ? 15 : 7) * scale)
            Spacer()
        }
        .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double(tick)/(60) * 360))
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the list in which I want to display the diffrent clocks

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
                  List(countryList) { countryItem in
                          HStack() {
                              Text(countryItem.name + ": " + countryItem.time)
                                  .frame(height: 80.0)
                              Spacer()
                              TestView()
                          }.padding(5)
                      }
                  .navigationBarTitle("App")
                }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the countries, where I get the name and the timezone for the clocks

```
struct Country: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let time: String
}

let countryList: [Country] = [
    Country(
        name: "New York",
        time: getLocalTimeZone(in: "America/New_York")),
    Country(
        name: "Paris",
        time: getLocalTimeZone(in: "Europe/Paris"))
]


func getLocalTimeZone(in timeZone: String) -> String {
    let f = DateFormatter()
    f.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
    f.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    return f.string(from: Date())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI
struct Country: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    //Since you need the identifier for the string and the clock it is best to have a variable for the identifier vs just the time string
    let timeZoneIdentifier: String
}
//You can use an extension to create other variables that use the primary ones
extension Country{
    ///Returns the TimeZone using the timeZoneIdentifier or the system timezone if not defined
    var timeZone: TimeZone{
        TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneIdentifier) ?? TimeZone.current
    }
    ///Returns a string with the current time in "HH:mm" format
    var time: String{
        Date().getLocalTimeZone(in: self.timeZone)
    }
}

struct WorldClockView: View {
    var countryList: [Country] = [
        Country(
            name: "New York",
            timeZoneIdentifier: "America/New_York"),
        Country(
            name: "Paris",
            timeZoneIdentifier: "Europe/Paris")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List(countryList) { countryItem in
                HStack() {
                    Text(countryItem.name + ": " + countryItem.time)
                        .frame(height: 80.0)
                    Spacer()
                    //Your clock will need the timeZone
                    ClockTestView(timeZone: countryItem.timeZone)
                }.padding(5)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("App")
        }
    }
}

struct WorldClockView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WorldClockView()
    }
}

//I made some changes to yout date extension so you can account for the time zone
extension Date {
    ///Returns the hour, minute and second date component in the provided timeZone
    func getComponents(timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current) -> (hour: Double, minutes: Double, seconds: Double){
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        //Calendar that includes a custom timezone
        calendar.timeZone = timeZone
        
        let hour: Double = Double(calendar.component(.hour, from: self))
        
        let minutes: Double = Double(calendar.component(.minute, from: self))
        
        let seconds: Double = Double(calendar.component(.second, from: self))
        
        return (hour, minutes, seconds)
    }
    ///Returns the angles for the hour, minute and second clock hands in the provided timeZone
    func getHandAngles(timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current) -> (hourAngle: Angle, minuteAngle: Angle, secondAngle: Angle ){
        let components = self.getComponents(timeZone: timeZone)
        
        let hourAngle: Angle  = Angle (degrees: (360 / 12) * (components.hour + components.minutes / 60))
        
        let minuteAngle: Angle = Angle(degrees: (components.minutes * 360 / 60))
        
        let secondAngle: Angle = Angle (degrees: (components.seconds * 360 / 60))
        
        return(hourAngle,minuteAngle,secondAngle)
    }
    //Moved this here to make it more resusable
    ///Returns a string with the current time in "HH:mm" format for the provided time zone
    func getLocalTimeZone(in timeZone: TimeZone) -> String {
        let f = DateFormatter()
        f.timeZone = timeZone
        f.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return f.string(from: self)
    }
}


struct ClockTestView: View {
    var clockSize: CGFloat = 100
    //Take in time zone to be used
    var timeZone: TimeZone
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                let scale = geometry.size.height / 200
                //Pass time zone to be used
                TickHands(scale: scale, timeZone: timeZone)
                ForEach(0..<60*4) { tick in
                    Ticks.tick(at: tick, scale: scale)
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: clockSize, height: clockSize)
    }
}
struct TickHands: View {
    var scale: Double
    @State var dateTime: Date = Date()
    //Take in timezone
    let timeZone: TimeZone
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    //Get the angles in 1 variable using time zone
    private var angles:(hourAngle: Angle, minuteAngle: Angle, secondAngle: Angle ) {
        dateTime.getHandAngles(timeZone: timeZone)
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Hand(inset: 65 * scale, angle: angles.hourAngle)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Hand(inset: 40 * scale, angle: angles.minuteAngle)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.5 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Hand(inset: 20 * scale, angle: angles.secondAngle)
                .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.5 * scale, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            Circle().fill(Color.orange).frame(width: 10 * scale)
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { (input) in
            self.dateTime = input
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you calculate `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` are adopting the same calendar instance, hence the same time zone is always used for such calculation.

Comment: Could we pass the minutes, seconds and hours when calling the view? Would that theoretically work?